# Adding items to a ListView from a Spinner doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-spinner

I have two ArrayLists in my app; one containing a list of all stations (`AllStations`) and one containing a list of stations that the user has select (`MyStations`).  The user will select the stations from the spinner, which contains all items from the AllStations arraylist, and it will add them the `myStations` arraylist. There is a list view which displays the data from the `myStations` arrayList.

At the moment when a user selects a station to add to the `mystations` arraylist, it adds it to "myStations" but the listview does not refresh. I have tried `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` I have spend a couple of day googling etc. and haven't found any reason why it's not refreshing. Can anyone help me?

```
public class MyStations extends Activity{

    ListView personalStations;
    Spinner spinner;
    ArrayList<String>AllStations = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String>MyStations = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> StationNames;
    ArrayAdapter<String> myStationNames;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_stations);
        assignStations();
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        StationNames = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, AllStations);
        spinner.setAdapter(StationNames);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
            {
                String selectedStation = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                MyStations.add(selectedStation);
                myStationNames.notifyDataSetChanged();
                TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                int size = MyStations.size();
                String sizes= String.valueOf(size);
                txt1.setText(sizes);


            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
            {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                 
            }
        });
        personalStations = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myStnList);
        myStationNames = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MyStations);
        personalStations.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyStations.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MyStations));
    }

    public void assignStations(){
        ImportData stationData = new ImportData();
        stationData.importStations();
        AllStations = stationData.getStationNames();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write:

```
personalStations = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myStnList);
myStationNames = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MyStations);
personalStations.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyStations.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MyStations));
```

From what I see you create an adapter and assign it to `myStationsNames` but on your `ListView` you set a new instance of an `ArrayAdapter`. In this case calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on `myStationsNames` will not do anything as it isn't tied to a widget. Are you sure you didn't want to write:

```
personalStations = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myStnList);
myStationNames = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MyStations);
personalStations.setAdapter(myStationsNames);
```